# centOS server ready ISO download

Tags: centos, virtualization, iso, optical-media

I want to install CentOS 5.6 Final 32bit into a virtual server i have access to. I do not want to download the full DVD -- but I am searching if there is a **MINIMAL** version available somewhere.

What i want to do is to install kloxo and act as a web server. So anybody knows where I can get the minimal installation CD?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 7):

You can carry out a [net install](http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/mirror.centos.org/5.6/isos/i386/CentOS-5.6-i386-netinstall.iso). This is a 10M iso file that boots and allows you to install the OS from the net.